# add images to toolbar

Tags: iphone

i have 5 UIbarButton items in a toolbar,
how can i set images on each barbutton,
i tried through IB, but it not coming up, how can i do it ptogrammatically?
one of bar button looks like this

aBar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"]style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(aMethod)];

i already conencted all barbuttons ion IB.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Should work with IB. Be sure that your button type is set to Custom maybe?

Comment: IB is shoeing whites patches instead of images.i have no idea why its not coming up wid images.

Comment: Are you sure your images are correct? They should be black/white on a transparent background.

Comment: i didnt knw that i hv to giv button inside uibarbuttons in toolbar.it working f9.thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

jus check if the a.png is added to your project.

Or first take create a UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];

also check if IBoutlets are correctly connected.

But mostly the problem is because the image returned is nil.